# What happened to the Jericho squad after the Firstborn was defeated?

Tags: video-games, jericho

We know that part of the [Jericho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clive_Barker%27s_Jericho) squad (Jones and Cole) was killed, just before the party with the Firstborn started. However the four (five?) remaining members defeated the Firstborn and then swam to escape the collapsing cave (the death of the Firstborn appears to have had some cataclysmic effect on the Box).

Did The Box remain intact and were the Jericho squad trapped inside it with all other previous "sealers"? Did they manage to escape into the real world? What happened to The Box and the other trapped souls? And what happened ultimately to Ross?

Comment: No publisher wanted to pick this game up, or those that did, wanted a heavy premium for the lack of sales of the first game. Truth be told, according to The PirateBay's analytics, this was one of the most downloaded games ever. If those who had downloaded it, actually bought it, we may have had a sequel. We're not getting a sequel though... This game kinda went the way of Undying. Superior in Popularity, just... didn't sell because it was too easy for people to download it. I know this because I'm [an insider...]

Comment: @Rodriguez: Well, that is interesting. If you are an insider allow me to give you some insights. I actually bought the game and couldn't play if for a long time because my hardware didn't support it. The ridiculous anti-piracy crap of today's games make them a pain to actually play. So whenever I try to play a game that I bought I cannot help but think that the experience would be significantly better if I had downloaded it. In my very humble opinion this is often the reason why good games don't take off. Publishers just love to annoy their customers and reward piracy. The devs pay the price.

Answer (score 1):

From the Wikipedia article:

> Rumours about a sequel to Jericho were confirmed when Clive Barker had announced his intention to make a sequel to the game. In an interview, Barker let slip that plot details include "an aircraft carrier in the middle of the ocean with exactly 666 children in its hold", and will reveal the fate of the remaining Jericho members, especially Ross, following the death of the Firstborn. [link](http://technology.timesonline.co.uk/tol/news/tech_and_web/gadgets_and_gaming/article2725558.ece)

Unfortunately, the article is behind a subscriber wall, so I can't really confirm that's what it says. Also, that was some years back, so the odds are decent that the plans fell through.

[Clive Barker's website entry for the game](http://www.clivebarker.info/jericho.html), does have [more quotes about the plans](http://www.clivebarker.info/othersold.html#codemasters) which support the above plot summary, but the most recent one dates back to 2007.

Answer (score 0):

When they killed the first born I think that allowed the box to be reopened seeing as how it was there to contain the bad guy and he got defeated. As for the team members besides Jones and Cole, I think it was implied that they survived with Ross still psychically piggy backing.

Comment: It would be great if you could further support what seems to be your opinion.

Comment: How the plot was described in game if they resealed the breach they would have been trapped in the box. Instead they chose to destroy the Firstborn it stands to reason they didn't get trapped in the box like the previous sealers seeing as how they didn't seal it. Sorry if there isn't much to back it up but that is what I got from the game itself and the wikipedia. Neither go into too much detail in those regards.